# Find the rule/ formula that creating following linear digit sequence

Tags: pattern-recognition

Find the rule/ formula that creating following linear digit sequence
using particular formula or linear equation digit sequence is advancing, we need to find out that formula. Given sequence could be based on one or more rule / one or more equations.

Find the rule/ formula that creating following linear digit sequence: 91, 87, 99, 40, 32, 22, 55, 90 ,10, 63, 49, 96, 80, 17, 79, 51, 30, 66, 47, 09, 59, 07, 84, 57, 28, 53, 93, **, 46, 36, 02, 20, 78, 02, 04, 99, 16, 71, 41, 72, 41, 47

Comment: What aspect of this sequence is supposed to be "linear"?

Comment: I found no match in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=91%2C+87%2C+99%2C+40%2C+32%2C+22&sort=&language=&go=Search), and nothing from the gfun package in Maple...

Comment: It would help an awful lot if you would supply the context in which this sequence arose. That might narrow down the range of formulas we'd have to look at.

Answer (score 3):

Good luck finding any linearity in that - I can't see anything. For visualization:

[image]